# Can we apply clear coat again after polishing?

Tags: paint-clearcoat

I did paint one panel of my car with dupli-color perfect match and applied clear coat. I did wet sanding, buffing, and polishing. But still some scratches are there. Is it okay to apply clear coat once again?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

In order to paint clear on it again, you actually need to do some more sanding, scratching the surface even more. With the newly-painted panel polished, new clear coat won't stick and will most likely peel off of what you have there already. You want to hit the surface with some 1000 grit wet sanding. This will give the surface a little roughness, something for the new clear coat to adhere to. While you're at it, takeout the major scratches you're talking about. Then you'll want to completely clean the surface, prepping it as you normally would before you spray. Then spray your clear coat.